# How do I enqueue an action after receiving value from first action lightning controller

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, controller

I have an action from which I get an Id from the server. After I get an Id from the server I want to use this vale in a second action. But I cant seen to get this to work. From My research I understood I have to call the second action within the first action but this isn't working.

I do not receive the ALERT2, so seems like it doesn't enter the first statement.

I tried the enqueueAction action within the first and after the first see below:

```
({
    create : function(component, event, helper) {
        var excelSheet = component.get("v.excelSheet");
        var action = component.get("c.saveExpense");
        action.setParams({
            expense : excelSheet
        });
        action.setCallback(this,function(a){
            var state = a.getState();
            if(state == "SUCCESS"){  
              var expenceId = component.set("v.expenceId",a.getReturnValue()["Id"]); 
              alert('expenceId '+JSON.stringify(a.getReturnValue()["Id"]));  

                if(expenceId != null  && !expenceId.isEmpty()){
                                    alert('ALERT2');  
                    var action_2 = component.get("c.GetExpense");                
                    action_2.setCallback(this,function(reponse){
                        var state = reponse.getState();
                        if(state == "SUCCESS"){
                           alert('return '+JSON.stringify(reponse.getReturnValue()));  
                            var newExcelSheet = component.set("v.excelSheet", reponse.getReturnValue());
                        }
                    });
                    //$A.enqueueAction(action_2);
                    alert('Record is updated Successfully2');   

                }
                alert('Record is Created Successfully');   
            } else if(state == "ERROR"){
                alert('Error in calling server side action');
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
        $A.enqueueAction(action_2);
    },
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar use case as you have described. What you will need here is something called "function chaining". You will need to have a second function in your controller/JS. This second function within the JS then takes care of calling the second action method. You will need to invoke the second function in the JS within the the response of the first action. Below is the way to do that:

```
myFirstFunction: function(component) {
    ....

    var action1 = component.get("c.getValueFromAction1");
    action1.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        var state = response.getState();
        if (state === "SUCCESS") {
        ...
        this.mySecondFunction(component, send params as required);
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action1);
},

mySecondFunction: function(component, params) {
    ...
    var action2 = component.get("c.getValueFromAction2");
    action2.setCallback(this, function(response) {
    ...
    ...
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action2);
}
```