# Using promises with aura component callbacks

Tags: lightning-aura-components, asynchronous, promises, init

I noticed there a number of questions listed regarding this topic but I don't have the time to parse through all of them and look for the relevant information. I was hoping someone could quickly answer this.

The following code is in a helper function that is called from the init of this aura component. As you can see in the code, the part I have commented out towards the bottom is the additional operation I'm trying to execute on the async operations above it. It seems aura handles this sort of thing in a very specific way with the .callBack into .enqueue pattern. How do I tap into this operation with promises or async/await so that I can run this additional operation that iterates over the returned values. I'm sure I could just work around this a different way but I'd rather execute this operation within the init as it is doing a check against the data it's pulling into the page to see if the page should even be editable.

```
    setup : function(component, event) {

    var action = component.get("c.getConfirmation");

    var recId = component.get("v.recordId");

    action.setParams({
        "recordId": recId
    });

    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        var state = response.getState();
        if (component.isValid() && state === "SUCCESS") {
            var confirm = response.getReturnValue();
            component.set("v.confirmation", response.getReturnValue());
            component.set("v.seasonId", confirm.Season__c);

            var showSBYB = false;
            var name = confirm.RecordType.Name;
            console.log("SBYB: "+name);

            if(name == "SBYB")
                showSBYB = true;

            component.set("v.showSBYB", showSBYB);

            this.getProductData(component, event);

            var addEvent = $A.get("e.c:SeasonEvent");
            addEvent.setParams({ "seasonId": recId });
            addEvent.fire();
        }
        else {
            //this.toggleSpinner(component, event);
            console.log("Get Confirmation Failed with state: " + state);
            console.log(response);
            // var errors = ["Survey Questions could not be retrieved"];
            // this.errorToast(component,event, errors);
        }
    });

    $A.enqueueAction(action);

    var action2 = component.get("c.getForms");
    action2.setParams({
        "recordId": recId
    });

    action2.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        var state = response.getState();
        console.log(state);
        if (component.isValid() && state === "SUCCESS") {
            const forms = response.getReturnValue();
            component.set("v.forms", response.getReturnValue());
            console.log(component.get('v.forms'));
            if(forms && forms.length > 0)
            {
                component.set("v.selectedForm", forms[0]);

                this.getFormLines(component, event);
            }
            else
            {
                this.noFormsError(component);
            }
        }
        else {
            console.log("Get Forms Failed with state: " + state);
            console.log(response);
            this.noFormsError(component);
        }
    });

    // Disable Order Entry Page due to a form having an actual ship date
    // const hasShipped = action2.returnValue.some(form => form['ActualShip__c'] != null);
    // if (hasShipped) {
    //     this.disableInputs(component);
    //     alert("Error: Order Entry Disabled - Actual Ship date present");
    // }

    $A.enqueueAction(action2);

    component.set("v.qty", 1);
    component.set("v.pmt", "O");
    component.set("v.orderCount", 0);
    component.set("v.totalValue", 0);
    component.set("v.totalLineItems", 0);
    component.set("v.orderValue", 0);
    component.set("v.selectedSuffix", null);
    component.set("v.selectedLineItems", 0);
    component.set("v.selectedItemCount", 0);
    component.set("v.selectedSubTotal", 0);
},
```

Comment: You can utilize something known as function chaining, I have implemented it in quite a few places. Refer to [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/213580/54851) if it helps.

Comment: Along with Jayant's comment, you can also see [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/204489/2984) for yet another demonstration thereof.